# What is the meaning of "treat" in Meals

Tags: meaning, food

> My mother sometimes packs a treat for us

What does this sentence mean?
I don't understand *treat* in this sentence.

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definition of treat as a noun?

Comment: Generally it would mean a bag of potato chips, a candy bar, or something else along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Treat:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/treat_2)

As it relates to meals you should understand "something unusually good", "a dish, dessert or something that people are usually fond of" and therefore  very pleasing.

(OLD)